# Division of $t^a-1$ by $t^b-1$

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ with $b\neq 0$ and $r$ is the remainder of $a$ when divided by $b$, how do you show that for all integers $t>1$ the remainder of $t^a-1$ when divided by $t^b-1$ is $t^r-1$?

I thought about using the euclidean algorithm, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

We have for $a\ge b$ 
 $$t^a-1= (t^b-1)t^{a-b}+t^{a-b}-1$$
hence by induction (because $a\bmod b=a-nb$ for some $n$) $$t^a-1\equiv t^{a\bmod b}-1\pmod{t^b-1} $$
Therefore 
$$\gcd(t^a-1,t^b-1)=\gcd(t^b-1,t^{a\bmod b}-1), $$
i.e., the Euclidean algorithm applied to such polynomials is in effect just the Euclidean algorithm applied to the  exponents.